# Flutter APP No static method isAtLeastS()Z Error

Tags: android, flutter

Recently I upgraded our project and then got the error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastS()Z in class Landroidx/core/os/BuildCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.os.BuildCompat' appears in /data/app/~~XXH9HAmVmVxYZSO_1I9Wxw==/cn.belltrip.sport_app-MevAzkTnqxnmkocH80ysNw==/base.apk)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:167)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:221)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:110)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    E/AndroidRuntime(11787):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    apply from: '../MobSDK.gradle'
    
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
    
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
            quiet true
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                shrinkResources false
                minifyEnabled false
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi', "armeabi-v7a", 'arm64-v8a'
                }
            }
    
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.baidu.mobstat:mtj-sdk:latest.integration'
    }
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
    dependencies:
      flutter_xupdate: ^2.0.1
      vibration: ^1.7.3
      encrypt: ^5.0.0
      flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
      flutter_app_badger: ^1.2.0
      jpush_flutter: 2.1.5
      device_info: ^2.0.2
      common_utils: ^2.0.2
      flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0
      badges: ^2.0.1
      quiver: ^3.0.1
      webview_flutter: ^2.0.12
      flutter_custom_dialog: ^1.1.0
      install_plugin: ^2.0.1
      url_launcher: 6.0.10
      flutter_downloader: ^1.7.0
      path_provider: ^2.0.3
      permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
      progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
      toast: ^0.1.5
      getwidget: ^2.0.4
      bot_toast: ^4.0.1
      audioplayers: ^0.20.0
      package_info: ^2.0.2
      flutter_html: ^2.1.2
      extended_image: ^4.2.1
      fish_redux: 0.3.7
      dio: 4.0.0
      shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
      fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
      flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0+2
      flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
      flutter_easyrefresh: ^2.2.1
      image_picker: ^0.8.4
      fijkplayer: ^0.10.0
      rxdart: ^0.27.2
      orientation: ^1.3.0
      intl: ^0.17.0
      websocket_manager: 0.2.2
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      connectivity: ^3.0.6
      flustars: ^2.0.1
      flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
      sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
      like_button: ^2.0.3
      pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
      flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
      wakelock: ^0.5.3+3
      bubble: ^1.2.1
      noripple_overscroll: ^0.0.2
      photo_view: ^0.12.0
      fluwx: ^3.6.1+1
      flutter_getuuid: ^0.0.1
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
      share: ^2.0.4
      sharesdk_plugin: ^1.3.0
      lpinyin: ^2.0.3
      flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
```

Flutter version: 2.5.3

Android Studio version: 2020.3.1 for Windows 64-bit

Please help me, thank you so much!